# Form Publisher triggering Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible have my form to trigger publication to a doc upon submission and then automatically trigger a signature add-on (for example "Dotted: Signature Creator")? Google Forms currently doesn't have any signature add-ons.

Comment: You can not trigger the "Dotted: Signature Creator" Add-on from Apps Script.  Apps Script is capable of doing something like merging Form Data into a Google Doc.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other solutions to include a signature pad in my Google Forms?

Comment: Unfortunately, the "live" Google Form can not be modified.  A Google Forms Add-on can affect a Google Form in edit mode, and process data after the Form is submitted, but there is no way to add special HTML or JavaScript to the live Google Form.  You would need to create an input form in an Apps Script Web App, or even use some other product.  I'm not familiar with what might be available for features in other forms products.  So, if you want the user to be able to sign from a Google Form, there is no "work around."  I don't know of any pre-made solution, and any other solution would be custom